# Java's Google Apps Provisioning API optionalAttribute IP_WHITELIST

Tags: google-provisioning-api

I'm creating a system to integrate a customer internal system with Google provisioning. One thing that arose was the meaning of the **IP_WHITELIST** optionalAttribute on the Java's Google Apps Provisioning API, [seen here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#creating_a_user_for_a_domain_experimental).

What does it do for the created user, as I didn't find any attribute on Google Apps' CPanel that matches this item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't do much of anything. By default it's always False but toggling it does not effect the user's ability to login from any IP address. My understanding is it was something Google was using but abandoned so it's the equivalent of a light switch with no wires running anywhere.